# How to traverse and fetch particular tag in HTML using DOM in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using the SimpleHTMLDom library in PHP and i am able to fetch the nodes from my HTML data.
For example i have a html data as below :

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>One</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
```

and i am using the parsing code as :

```
foreach($html->find('td') as $element)
echo $element->plaintext . '<br>';
```

But this code gives result as :

```
One<br/>
Two<br/>
Three<br/>
```

What i want is that i want the result "One" in say variable $one, "Two" in $two and "Three" in $three.
The problem is that how can i get a particular table column  element in a particular variable. I want to traverse irrespective of ID or class. Like I want to get like 3rd occurrence of the  tag in the HTML data. Thanks. The SIMPLEHTMLDOM.sourceforge.com manual is not understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find()` method accepts a second optional parameter: the *index* of the element.

```
echo $html->find('td', 2);
```

Output:

> Three

**nb1: if *index* is set, it returns the Nth element object, otherwise, return an array of object.**

**nb2: the parameter is zero based, it means that the the index of the first element is `0`**

You can also use the array to access to your element:

```
$elements = $html->find('td');
echo $elements[2];
```

Output:

> Three

doc: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm

Comment: Thanks alot. This was exactly what i was searching for. Also thanks for the manual api link :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo getElementByIndex(3); //whatever element you are looking for.

function getElementByIndex($indexOfElement) {
    $i = 1; //or 0 depending on starting list index
    foreach($html->find('td') as $element) {
        $i++;
        if ($i == $indexOfElement)
        return $element->plaintext . '<br>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but problem is isn't the <br/> tag, End of line is not required. What my problem is that how to get a particular value when i have too many of same tags in the code. Like there are 3 <td> tag but i just want the value of just one <td> tag.

Comment: Maybe i should save fetched tags value in PHP array. Let me try.

Comment: thanks alot for the function. But find('tag',index) did the work.